# Rotation angle of image grid

Tags: image-processing

I have the following image and would like to determine the rotation angle of the grid.

[image]

To detect the horizontal and vertical lines I use `EdgeDetect`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpnVD.png"];
ed = 5;
edgeImg = EdgeDetect[img, ed];
lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect[img, ed]];(*get lines*)
imgWithLines = HighlightImage[img, {Red, Thickness[0.002], Line /@ lines}]
```

[image]

Angle of horizontal lines (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8m19.png)):

```
horizontalLines = Cases[lines, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} /; a == 0 && c == 1600];

horizontalAngles = horizontalLines /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> ArcTan[Abs[d - b]/Abs[c - a]]*180/Pi;

selectHorizontalAngles = Select[horizontalAngles, # > 10^-3 &];

Mean[selectHorizontalAngles]

0.0809717
```

Angle of vertical lines (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuKXi.png)):

```
verticalLines = Cases[lines, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} /; a != 0 && c != 1600];

verticalAngles = verticalLines /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> 90 - ArcTan[Abs[d - b]/Abs[c - a]]*180/Pi;

selectVerticalAngles = Select[verticalAngles, # > 10^-3 &];

Mean[selectVerticalAngles]

0.230593
```

I cannot believe that the angle calculated from horizontal and vertical lines differ so much. May be I made somewehere an error?

**How would you determine the rotation angle of the grid?**

Comment: Is the image only rotated, not tilted? I.e., are you sure that the line of sight is perfectly perpendicular to the grid? Also, how perfect is the grid?

Comment: This is a good remark - thank you. It would be interesting to see another solution to exclude any programming error.

Comment: Why aren't you using two-argument arctangent for computing the angles?

Comment: @J. M: Thank you for the hint.